# How to pass two values from ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Currently I'm pass one value from ajax to php using onlick event.this is my onclick

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $row['cat_id'];?>" onclick="showCat(this.id)" >click </a>
```

and this is my ajax code

```
function showCat(id) {
    //get the selected value

    //make the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_categ.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {option : id},
        success: function(data) {
           document.getElementById('meal').innerHTML =data;
        }
    });

}
```

what i want to do is,i want to pass another value from ajax code.
this is  i want to pass value

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $resname;?>" name="another"  />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get text box value using `$("input[name='another']").val()` and it can be passed to ajax call parameter which is mentioned in code.

```
function showCat(id) {
     var resname = $("input[name='another']").val();  //here you can getvalue of your textbox
    //make the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_categ.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {option : id, resname : resname},
        success: function(data) {
           document.getElementById('meal').innerHTML =data;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your function so it accepts two parameters:

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $row['cat_id'];?>" onclick="showCat(this.id, '<?php echo $resname;?>')" >click </a>

function showCat(id, resname) {
    //get the selected value

    //make the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_categ.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {option : id, resname: resname},
        success: function(data) {
           document.getElementById('meal').innerHTML =data;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. pass two argument in `all_task()`**

```
onclick="all_task('<?=$all?>','<?=$project_id?>');"
```

**2. then in Ajax file:**

```
function all_task(val,project_id){

if(val!=''){

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"ajax_alltask.php",
        data: '&all_val='+val+'&project_id='+project_id,
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(response){
            if(response!=''){
                $('.modal-body').html(response);
            }
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @shwetakushwaka! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.